# Should I always make an Identity column Primary Key for the table?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, primary-key, identity

If I create a table with Identity column, should I always make it PK for the table. I know when we do it automatically creates a clustered index for that table. Is there any perfomance hit keeping all identity columns in tables without making them PK? Any suggestions?

Comment: Using an `INT IDENTITY` as your clustering index is one of the **best options** you have. Using it is definitely a **good thing!**

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use that table in C# using linq then there will need to put PK.